# Convert a spec file to debian

Tags: ubuntu, centos, rpm, deb, specifications

We are migrating our servers from CentOS to ubuntu. For a self written application we created a spec file to create RPM's for easy installation on CentOS. Now we want to convert it to the debian format. What is the simplest way to do it? I don't mean creating from the rpm a .deb file but converting the spec file to an ubuntu control file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical answer seems to revolve around [`alien`](http://joeyh.name/code/alien/) [`--generate`](http://alnahian.wordpress.com/tag/alien-generate/).

Answer (score 2):

I have written [spec2deb](https://bitbucket.org/gdraheim/spec2deb) for that purpose.

Comment: this script does not work for https://github.com/CpanelInc/ea-apache2/blob/master/SPECS/ea-apache24.spec